# Нужна ли запятая перед СЛОВНО в следующих предложениях?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Скажите, нужна ли запятая в предложениях:

*Ты говоришь так, словно я делаю это специально.

Огни, словно маяки.*

Answer (score 3):

1) Запятая нужна в сложноподчиненном предложении (указательное слово ТАК, союз СЛОВНО): Ты говоришь так, словно я делаю это специально.

2) Запятая не нужна в простом предложении, союз СЛОВНО находится между подлежащим и сказуемым: Огни словно маяки.